# Font Awesome styling - Same icon different CSS

Tags: css, fonts, icons, font-awesome

I am running into a road block styling a font awesome icon in two places of my site. I have researched this particular topic and have not found an answer.

The plus icon of `fa-plus` are in two places of a site (mobile menu and product detail page).

I would like to position the icon `float: right` on the mobile menu but not on the product detail page. When I implement the css code below, the plus icon changes position on the product detail page as well. How can we float the icon on the right and not the other placement on the site?

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a second class to the markup of the icon for the mobile menu, something like this:

```
<i class="fa faFloat"></i>
```

Then move your `float: right;` out of the `.fa` section, and place it in a new one like so:

```
.faFloat {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: or maybe use .pull-right class to that icon, I think its defined in the font awesome css; also you have a typ-o: flaot -> float